# hermitian matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, spectral-graph-theory

$A$ is a hermitian matrix with dimension $n$.

$x_i$ belongs to Orthonormal system $(1 < i \leq n)$, $X$　and their norm is $1$.

$\lambda_i$'s are the eigenvalues of $A$.

How to prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^q x_iAx_i^T \geq \sum_{i=1}^q\lambda_i $$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference mathjax references. try to learn how to type maths for this website.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}$

Let's consider the matrix $XAX^T$, in particular observe that the $i$-th diagonal entries can be written as $x_iAx_i^T$.

Hence $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iAx_i^T =trace(XAX^T)=trace(AXX^T)$$

Can you complete the proof now?

Edit: (to handle $q$ and ordered eigenvalues)

Assuming that you are working with real matrices.

Let $A=UDU^T$, where $D=diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$.

Let $y_i = x_i U$, notice that $y_i$ is a new set of orthonormal system.

$$\sum_{i=1}^q x_iAx_i^T=\sum_{i=1}^q y_i Dy_i^T=\sum_{i=1}^q \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j y_{ij}^2=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\left(\sum_{i=1}^qy_{ij}^2 \right)$$

Let $z_j = \sum_{i=1}^q y_{ij}^2$, we have$$\sum_{i=1}^q x_iAx_i^T=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jz_j$$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n y_{ij}^2 = 1$, we have $0 \leq z_j \leq 1.$

Also, we have $\sum_{j=1}^nz_j=q$.

Hence a lower bound can be found by solving the following optimization problem:

$$\min_w \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_jw_j$$

subject to

$$ 0 \leq w_j \leq 1$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^nw_j = q$$

Comment: Sorry,still I cannot

Comment: can you evaluate $XX^T$? keyword: orthonormal

Comment: it can solve equality but not unequality

Comment: ah, I see the question has been edited.

Comment: Are $x_i$ and $\lambda_i$ related in the edited question? How are $\lambda_i$ sorted?

Comment: oh no, I forget to mention it. λ1.... <= .... λi <= ....  λn and 0 < q <= n

Comment: Edited to handle your new question.

Comment: sorry for asking you too much but how about then?

Comment: yeah,I finally solve it

Comment: congratulations.

Comment: thank you! I finnally solve the problem!